# CSS classes are being read from files which are not imported in the component

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a weird problem with CSS files and importing them. I have a bunch of .jsx files with my react components and each of them have individual .css files for styling. The problem is that in some cases when I do this in some ex_file.jsx

```js
import './ex_file.css';
import React from 'react';
```

and then try to use imported class

```html
<div className="example-class">
  Some text
</div>
```

The class which gets applied doesn't come from the .css file imported at the top of the .jsx file. Is this the expected behaviour? From what I googled there was no mention of that. Obviously I can give unique names to each css class but I was wondering if there was a way to fix that.

Comment: Yes, because css rules are global. You can use `styled-components`, `emotion` or `css modules` to generate a unique class name and apply styles to each one.

Comment: Thanks, css modules work perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The class which gets applied doesn't come from the .css file imported
> at the top of the .jsx file. Is this the expected behaviour?

Yes, because the CSS rules that are defined in any of the imported files are not specifically scoped to their components.

> Obviously I can give unique names to each css class but I was
> wondering if there was a way to fix that.

Giving unique names manually is one way to fix that. But you can use things like [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) etc.

Comment: Thank you that is just perfect, I've used CSS Modules as you suggested and [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) to easily use multiple classes. Thank's a ton!

Answer (score 0):

In case you're reusing same class names between css files, they all factor in the final styling of all elements with same classes. There are several ways to solve this:

- Create an unique class name for top level DOM element, then by using nesting functionality of CSS preprocessors such as LESS/SASS/SCSS you would get unique styling. (or CSS modules)
- css-in-js

Comment: Thanks, I've used css modules with classnames and it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css modules. check this link

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/?

It generates a local css file for each component,so you will not have name collisions.

Comment: Others have suggested the same thing and it is indeed what I've been looking for, thank you!